# Making web service calls with WCF client + cookies

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, authentication, cookies

Been implementing the `Basic security Authentication` in a `WCF Service.`

Managed to get the `.ASPXCookie` from the web service. But, how to pass along the received cookie back to the next request?

```
var authClient = new MovieDbClient();
using (new OperationContextScope(authClient.InnerChannel))
{
    isValid = authClient.Login("userName", "passWord*");
    if (isValid)
    {
        var response = (HttpResponseMessageProperty)OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name];
        sharedCookie = response.Headers["Set-Cookie"];
    }
}
```

I tried to print the `SharedCookie` and was successful in it.
It looks something like,

```
".ASPXAUTH=E499CA76EAC178A96BE5CA1E314CC90E0A6F9B95AD221EF5AD7D43598E701DC034D40904DBB8ECFBFB3EA21F2597D3C8DAB9B19A0491FD5858E9F0A4B6DC6E6A980FBB4CCADE191855A029CF8236C6890BEE28665C236992632807D1021AA138; expires=Tue, 07-Jan-2014 06:22:22 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly"
```

The question is `how do I pass this cookie information in my next request using wCF Client - authClient` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To add a Cookie header to the WCF request in the current context given that you have the cookie string already:

```
var prop = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
prop.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, sharedCookie);
OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, prop);
```

Comment: Note, that the great solution of Nicholas W only works, if the flag "AllowCookies" is NOT set to "true" in the Binding of the app.config ServiceModel !!! > http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2011/11/managing-cookies-in-wcf-client.html