# How can I authenticate my client side application through NetIQ Access Manager?

Tags: c#, soap, proxy, wsdl, netiq

I have a client side application (C#) designed to gather and analyze metrics and output a wide range of tables/charts in Excel. The metrics are related to bug/issue tracking, which we have just begun using a third party application (FIT BugTrack) to do. FIT allows access through SOAP. Originally, we had a development environment of FIT set up within our own firewall. Using the .wsdl from FIT, I was able to add a service reference in Visual Studio, giving me access to classes useful for gathering information from FIT in a simple manner. I was able to ask the user for their username/password and pass this to my request class, getting the desired information returned successfully.

For security reasons, the "live" version of FIT is housed in a DMZ, outside of our primary firewall. When entering the address to access FIT, the user is redirected to a NetIQ Access Manager login page. Upon entering valid credentials, this access manager redirects the user to FIT, automatically logged in.

With this NetIQ Access Manager in place, my application no longer has access, since is seems that authentication is being granted by the AM, not FIT itself. I am unfamiliar with gaining programmatic access through a "firewall" like this, so I'm not even sure what kind of information I am looking for. Is it possible that something in the configuration level of this Access Manager is set up to restrict the very thing I'm trying to accomplish? I need to find a way to authenticate my application through the access manager, then use the classes generated from FIT's .wsdl to gather data.

Any suggestions that might point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Also, if there is any other information needed, I will try my best to provide it upon request.

Comment: NetIQ access manager has support for several authentication schemes, including Social, TOTP, RADIUS, Mutual SSL, ORed, and OpenID. You'll need to authenticate with one of those. Have a read through the NetIQ documentation. Additionally, if it's sitting on a DMZ, you'll likely need your firewall guys involved to put some pinholes in for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll look into some of the authentication schemes you mentioned to try to pinpoint the right direction to move. As far as the documentation goes, I've skimmed over a few things, but saw nothing that seemed like the solution. Might be that I'm still in the phase of not being completely sure what I'm looking for yet.

Comment: See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/190806/Send-Cookies-When-Making-WCF-Service-Calls, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20964871/making-web-service-calls-with-wcf-client-cookies, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/624fb3f9-222d-4795-9140-fe9ef3934361/add-cookie-to-calls?forum=wcf.